# Remotely access certificate store using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following script which brings back any certificates on the local machine needed for our VPN client and shows the expiry date:

```
$asset = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Set-Location cert:\LocalMachine\My

Write-Host = "Asset ID:"$asset

Get-ChildItem -Recurse cert: | select subject, notafter

write-host "`n"

Read-Host "Press any key to exit..."

(Get-Host).SetShouldExit(0)
```

It runs perfectly on my local machine, bring back the following:

```
Subject                                              NotAfter                                            
-------                                              --------                                            
CN=HW008551D.hca.local                               21/07/2018 09:46:08
```

Is there a way I can run this on a remote machine, which looks at that machines certificate store rather than the local machines?

I have tried a few different methods but unable to find anything that works

Comment: `Invoke-Command -computername $asset -scriptblock {Get-ChildItem -Recurse cert: | select subject, notafter}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the PSRemoting configured. Then you can use the *Invoke-Command* to get your job done.

```
$Computername= 'remotecomputer'
$RemoteMachine_cred =Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computername  -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Recurse cert: | select subject, notafter} -Credential $RemoteMachine_cred
```

Links to configure PSRemoting:

1) [Use Remote Commands in PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)

2) [Run PS Commands on Remote Computers](https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/)

Note: You can put all the script inside a scriptblock and you can pass it as a value of scriptblock in single shot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tested on a test network and this works great, unfortunately the way our domain is setup, I can't get it to run successfully remotely. I've created a workaround using a batch file which is run locally on the machine and this will do the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: I had following issue when I tried to read all certificates from the remote machine: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/12463893-bug-get-childitem-throws-terminating-errors-brows